# JSONObject string is not stored in sharedpreferences

Tags: android, json, parsing, sharedpreferences

I am passing a jsonobject string value to my shared preferences and commiting it. But while fetching this, its returning the default value.

For putting :

```
public void new_putMultipleProfileData(String got_multiple_json_data){

    Editor editor=app_prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(NEW_TESTING_PIC_ID, got_multiple_json_data);
    editor.commit();
}
```

For getting :

```
public String new_getMultipleProfileData(){
    return app_prefs.getString(NEW_TESTING_PIC_ID,"0");
}
```

Complete Preference Helper Class :

```
public class PreferenceHelper {


private final String PREF_NAME = "Testing_xyz";
private SharedPreferences app_prefs;

//For Testing
public static final String NEW_TESTING_PIC_ID = "testing";

private Context context;

public PreferenceHelper(Context context) {
    app_prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    this.context = context;
}


public void new_putMultipleProfileData(String got_multiple_json_data){
    AppLog.Log("new_data_80503","got_multiple_json_data "+got_multiple_json_data);
    Editor editor=app_prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(NEW_TESTING_PIC_ID, "hello");
    editor.commit();
}

public String new_getMultipleProfileData(){
    AppLog.Log("new_data_80503","new_getMultipleProfileData "+app_prefs.getString(NEW_TESTING_PIC_ID,"0"));
    return app_prefs.getString(NEW_TESTING_PIC_ID,"0");
}
```

}

Comment: how are you initialising app_prefs ?

Comment: @Pr38y private SharedPreferences app_prefs;

Comment: @Pr38y public PreferenceHelperClass(Context context) {
        app_prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.context = context;
    }

Comment: Please add your `PreferenceHelperClass` code.

Comment: Are you storing and accessing data from different contexts/activities

Comment: @Pr38y Yes. I am storing data in 1st activity and trying to access that in 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same preference manager across the app then use `defaultSharedPreference`. `getSharedPreferences` return preference file for that context only, it is different for different context.

`SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

or

you can use `ApplicationContext` instead of `context`

Comment: But putting different data, in the prefs , is working fine using getDefaultSharedPreferences. What is the difference between the two ?

Comment: getSharedPreferences return preference file for that context only, it is different for different context. getDefaultSharedPreferences return one file for the entire app , irrespective of the context. Your current code is creating two `PREF_NAME ` xml files, one for activity A and other for activity B. You're saving data in Activity A's file. And accessing from activity B's file